# Stack overflow with assoc and a function test

Tags: lisp, stack-overflow

I wrote this function, that returns t if the arguments given match, else nil.

```
(defun match (input-form pattern)
  (cond
    ((and (not input-form) (not pattern)) t)
    ((not pattern) nil)
    ((eq (car pattern) '*) (or (match input-form (cdr pattern)) (match (cdr input-form) pattern)))
    ((not input-form) nil)
    ((and (> (length (string (car pattern))) 1) (eq (char (string (car pattern)) 0) '#\?))
            (match (cdr input-form) (cdr pattern)) )
    ((eql (car input-form) (car pattern)) (match (cdr input-form) (cdr pattern))) ) )
```

When I do this :

```
(setq patterns 
    '(((bonjour *) bonjour) ((salut *) salut)) )

(assoc '(bonjour Eliza) patterns :test #'match)
```

It works well and returns : `((bonjour *) bonjour)`

and `(assoc '(hello Eliza) patterns :test #'match)`
works well too and returns nil.

But when I add patterns to the variable patterns like this :

```
(setq patterns 
'(((bonjour *) bonjour) ((salut) salut) ((* mere * pere *) parlez-moi de vos parents) ((mere *) la mere de qui) ((* mere) parlez-moi de votre mere)) )
```

When I ask for something that matches, it works, but when I ask for something that doesn't match, I get a stack overflow error message.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [`(trace match)`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm), you will get the answer right away (just remember to hit <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> quickly enough :-):

```
  0: (MATCH (BONJOUR2 ELIZA) (BONJOUR *))
  0: MATCH returned NIL
  0: (MATCH (BONJOUR2 ELIZA) (SALUT))
  0: MATCH returned NIL
  0: (MATCH (BONJOUR2 ELIZA) (* MERE * PERE *))
    1: (MATCH (BONJOUR2 ELIZA) (MERE * PERE *))
    1: MATCH returned NIL
    1: (MATCH (ELIZA) (* MERE * PERE *))
      2: (MATCH (ELIZA) (MERE * PERE *))
      2: MATCH returned NIL
      2: (MATCH NIL (* MERE * PERE *))
        3: (MATCH NIL (MERE * PERE *))
        3: MATCH returned NIL
        3: (MATCH NIL (* MERE * PERE *))
          4: (MATCH NIL (MERE * PERE *))
          4: MATCH returned NIL
          4: (MATCH NIL (* MERE * PERE *))
            5: (MATCH NIL (MERE * PERE *))
            5: MATCH returned NIL
            5: (MATCH NIL (* MERE * PERE *))
```

I.e., you need to test for `(null input-form)` *before* stepping through the pattern:

```
(defun match (input-form pattern)
  (cond
    ((and (null input-form) (null pattern)) t)
    ((or (null pattern) (null input-form)) nil)
    ((eq (car pattern) '*) 
     (or (match input-form (cdr pattern)) 
         (match (cdr input-form) pattern)))
    ((and (> (length (string (car pattern))) 1) 
             (char= (char (string (car pattern)) 0) #\?))
     (match (cdr input-form) (cdr pattern)))
    ((eql (car input-form) (car pattern))
     (match (cdr input-form) (cdr pattern)))))
```

Please note the indentation and whitespace changes I made to your code, as well as using [`null`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_null.htm) instead of [`not`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_not.htm) when checking for empty lists (might consider [`endp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_endp.htm) instead too).

Comment: Thank you for your response ;)
First thank for the advices for indentation and using null.
I tried to trace match as well, but din't think to trace and to test with assoc. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, because (Hello Eliza) doesn't match with (Hello *), but Im trying to fix it.

Comment: Ok, I add this test : ((and (eq (car pattern) '*) (eq (cdr pattern) nil)) t) to avoid problems when the pattern finishes with * and it works, thank you a lot